# Convert Access select multiple Last() to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have MS Access syntax like below:

[image: select multiple last]

I need to convert it to SQL server syntax.

I know the meaning of Last(), but I have no idea how to make this multiple Last() work with a single group by in SQL server.

Comment: I suppose it's enough to replace LAST with MAX and this query will work not only in SQL Server

Comment: create a seperate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by looking at you query, you may have multiple records in your table having same patientid and dateallocated; but you want only one of them to be returned.
you wrote :

```
patandmaxdate.maxdate = psapure.datecollected 
and patandmaxdate.patientid = psapure.patientid
```

this is returning more then one record and to filter this you used select last()....group by...
I think this may help you in this situation:

```
select patientid,dateollected,psaid,psavalue
from
(select *,
 row_number() over(partition by patientid order by dateollected desc) as RowNumber
 from psapure) as t
where RowNumber = 1
```

sample [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e380b/5)

note: it doesn't contain any filter condition for psavalue and psaid so it may differ with data. to add some filter on these you may use query like this :

```
select patientid,dateollected,psaid,psavalue
from
(select *,
 row_number() over(partition by patientid order by dateollected desc,psavalue desc,psaid desc) as RowNumber
 from psapure) as t
where RowNumber = 1
```

sample [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e380b/6)

Comment: @tianxu0836 - you should create a seperate question.